# Magento2: change layout if category has no products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Attempting to change the layout of the category page from 2 columns to 1 column, if the category has no products. I have a working solution for Magento 1, just not sure what approach would be best for Magento 2. Any help is appreciated.

**Magento 1 example:**

```
class Empty_category_Model_Observer {

public function zeroproducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controller   = $observer->getAction();

    //limit to the product view page
    if ($controller->getFullActionName() != 'catalog_category_view')
    {
        return;
    }

    $_productCollection = $observer->getEvent()
        ->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection();

    $products = clone $_productCollection;

    if(!$products->count()):
        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()
                 ->getBlock('root')
                 ->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
    endif;

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using **plugin**

- Create a di xml file to define your plugin

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
        <plugin name="plugin_category" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Category\View"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

- Create your plugin

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Category;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject, $result)
    {
        $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if(!$category->getProductCollection()->getSize()){
            $result->getConfig()->setPageLayout('1column');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bro Worked